# Restore previous session after automatic log off in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to implement feature in my WPF application like if someone has log in and he is filling a  registration form,but after sometime the account is automatically logout(already implemented this feature),then when the user sign in again, then how to display him the application in the same old state i.e the half filled form or anything he was doing previously with his account,i am looking on net but unable to find any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no quick easy way to do this... However, I would do it like this.

Use the MVVM pattern.  As the user enters info into the View, your ViewModel will get the data.  When the user logs out, your application should serialize your ViewModel to your favorite format.  Mine is JSON.  Using JSON.NET, you can serialize the viewmodel out to file.

On startup, you would deserialize the file and restore your viewmodel.  Voila, your view should be right back to where it was when they closed the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have made it-
MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="SerializeDeSerialize.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Nikita="clr-namespace:SerializeDeSerialize"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closed="Window_Closed_1" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Nikita:Movie></Nikita:Movie>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Name="lblTitle" Content="Title:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,25,63,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="164"></Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Name="txtTitle" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,25,63,10" Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Name="lblRating" Content="Rating:" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,25,63,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="164"></Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Name="txtRating" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,25,63,10" Text="{Binding Rating}"></TextBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Name="lblReleaseDate" Content="Release Date:" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="10,25,63,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="164"></Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Name="txtReleaseDate" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,25,63,10" Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}"></TextBox>

            <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Window1" Margin="66,36,69,10" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Content="Window2" Margin="66,36,69,10" Click="Button_Click_2"></Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SerializeDeSerialize
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SerializeDeSerialize.Movie mv = new Movie();
        static Movie mm = new Movie();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = mv;

        }

        private void Window_Closed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerializeToXML(mv);
        }

        static public void SerializeToXML(Movie movie)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Movie));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\398780\Desktop\Nikita\movie.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, movie);
            textWriter.Close();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mm=DeserializeFromXML();
            txtTitle.Text = mm.Title;
            txtRating.Text =Convert.ToString(mm.Rating);
            txtReleaseDate.Text = Convert.ToString(mm.ReleaseDate);

        }

        static Movie DeserializeFromXML()
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Movie));
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\398780\Desktop\Nikita\movie.xml");
            mm=(Movie)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);

            textReader.Close();

            return mm;
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 win1 = new Window1();
            win1.Show();
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 win2 = new Window2();
            win2.Show();
        }
    }
}

MVVM-movie.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SerializeDeSerialize
{
    public class Movie
    {
        private string _title;
        private int _rating;
        private DateTime _releaseDate;

        public Movie()
        {
        }
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }

        public int Rating
        {
            get { return _rating; }
            set { _rating = value; }
        }

        public DateTime ReleaseDate
        {
            get { return _releaseDate; }
            set { _releaseDate = value; }
        }
    }
}

Please check..it is same as you told or not?
```

Comment: I have used XML for serialization

Comment: Yep, that's pretty close.  It's not exactly MVVM, but you're the judge as to whether it does what you want.  True MVVM would completely divorce the view and the view model, but otherwise this is what I had in mind.